# Core Data: Can a NSPredicate in fetchResultsController return multiple objects for each row, into my Table View?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Can a fetchedResultsController return an Array of Arrays? Or An array of NSSets?

Code below is an example, of what I'm trying to do. Is it possible?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //...
    NSSet *objects = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //...
}
```

The reason I'm doing this, is: if the user swipes the cell, and deletes it. I need all objects  from that row deleted. And I also need to display data on that Cell, from calculation made on all the clocks for that Day/Row.

Here's my Core Data Model:

[image]

Each row must contain all Clock objects, for a given day, based on it's clockIn property. clockIn is a NSDate  object. One row should represent one day.

Could I get help figuring out a predicate for this? Is it even possible?

Also, I'm already using sections in my Table View. So these are out of the question.
There is one solution that I rather no go for, which is to create Year, Month and Day, Entities. This would fix. But it seems odd that I need to do that, considering the my clockIn property should give me everything I need.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just do `Work *work = [_fetchResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]; NSSet *clocks = work.clock`? (You can also pass options to the NSFetchedResultsController to make this faster by pre-fetching that relationships.)

Comment: Hi! `Work *work = [_fetchRe...` would be returning 1 row only. I need all clocks from a given day, in such a way that 1 row is one day only. In other words: One row has all clocks from one given day. And this must be made based on Clock's clockIn attribute.

Comment: What does your fetch request look like?

Comment: `entityForName:@"Clock"` and `predicateWithFormat:@"work == %@", self.work` unfortunatly, this returns 1 row for each clock. I also think I might found an answer here:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839556/nspredicate-something-equivalent-of-sqls-group-by) meaning I don't think I can resolve the way I'm trying to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it can't.

As stated here: [NSPredicate something equivalent of SQL's GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839556/nspredicate-something-equivalent-of-sqls-group-by)

"CoreData is an object graph management framework, not a SQL data store. Thus, you should—as quickly as possible—get yourself out of the SQL mindset."

And in regard to the question in hands:

"NSPredicate is intended as a—no surprise—predicate for qualifying objects in the object graph. Thus you can fetch all the objects that match a query, but that is not the same as grouping those results. If you want to do aggregate operations, use Key-Value coding's collection operators. Under the hood, Core Data may convert these to sensible SQL, but that's exclusively an implementation detail."

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in a few lines of code with [TLIndexPathTools](http://tlindexpathtools.com) by subclassing `TLIndexPathController`, an alternative to `NSFetchedResultsController`. I have not tested this, but here is a mockup of what it could look like:

```
#import <TLIndexPathController.h>
@interface GroupedIndexPathController : TLIndexPathController
@end

#import "GroupedIndexPathController.h"
#import "TLIndexPathSectionInfo.h"
@implementation GroupedIndexPathController

- (void)setDataModel:(TLIndexPathDataModel *)dataModel
{
    NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:dataModel.numberOfSections];
    for (TLIndexPathSectionInfo *sectionInfo in dataModel.sections) {
        if (sectionInfo.objects) {
            [items addObject:sectionInfo.objects];
        }
    }
    TLIndexPathDataModel *groupedDataModel = [[TLIndexPathDataModel alloc] initWithItems:items andSectionNameKeyPath:nil andIdentifierKeyPath:nil];
    [super setDataModel:groupedDataModel];
}

@end
```

What you'd do is to set up the index path controller's fetch request with `sectionNameKeyPath` set to the property you want to group by. When the fetch is performed, the parent class will then generate a data model organized into sections. The above code overrides the `dataModel` property setter, mapping the sections into a single section of grouped objects like:

**Sectioned Data Model**

```
Section 0
    Managed Object 0.0
    Managed Object 0.1
    Managed Object 0.2
Section 1
    Managed Object 1.0
    Managed Object 1.1
```

**Grouped Data Model**

```
Section 0
    [Managed Object 0.0, Managed Object 0.1, Managed Object 0.2]
    [Managed Object 1.0, Managed Object 1.1]
```

This grouped data model is then passed to super's `dataModel` property setter. The table view controller will only ever see the grouped data model. The sectioned data model will be completely internal to `GroupedIndexPathController`. If the fetch results change, `GroupedIndexPathController` will report the updates to the grouped data model through the `controller:didUpdateDataModel:` delegate method and `TLTableViewController` will perform the batch updates for you automatically.

TLIndexPathTools provides several sample projects, the [Core Data example](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Core%20Data/Core%20Data/CoreDataCollectionViewController.m) demonstrates how to integrate with Core Data. You'd just need to supply an instance of `GroupedIndexPathController` instead of the standard `TLIndexPathController`.

You mentioned that your table uses sections. If you can elaborate I can modify the above to fit your specific requirements.